# How to pass secret key to backend(node js) from frontend(angular 4) using JWT

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, jwt, angular2-jwt

I am learning web application and just started with jwt authentication.

I understand the general flow. How jwt tokens are created by backend and how frontend retrieves that passes in every subsequent requests .

But in every online tutorial or youtube tutorial videos it is mentioned we need a signature to create a token which contains a secret key only known by the client. But in all the front end tutorial they are sending bearer token where the use of secret key is not shown.

Could someone tell me how to pass the secret key along with the token to server ?

Comment: you can find relevant info in this article
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: You do not need to pass secret key, it will be store in your application mostly in config file.A jwt token is created using secret key and attached to request on registration, after that when ever you hitting any request you have to pass token and secret key is used to decode your token, it can not be on client side.

Comment: So, here's my doubt if client only needs to send the token then anyone can get the token and send it to the server at server side the token will be verified with the secret key, so where is the security ?

Answer (score 0):

okey let first understand the process of jwt authentification first of all the secret key is generated in the backend once a user log in for the first time the backend server check if the user exist and in the response of the login request the server encode a token with a secret word and a unique information related to the user usually the user id   and a time validation when the token will be expired

```
 const payload = {
      sub: user.id,
      exp: moment().add(EXPIRATION_DAYS_NUMBER, CONSTANTS.TIME_UNITY).unix()
    }
    let token = jwt.encode(payload, CONSTANTS.JWT_SECRET)
```

once the token is encoded the server send it in the response of the login request the client side grap this token and store it in the local storage  the client now should use token for any future communication with the server that requires authentification in each http call that require authentication we send the token in the header so the server will check the header in a middelware    and decode the token witch the same JWT_SECRT to know if it is a valid token or not

```
middelware(req,res,next)
 let token = req.headers.authorization
  let payload = jwt.decode(token, CONSTANTS.JWT_SECRET)
  user.findOne({ id: payload.sub }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.forbidden('not authorized')
    next()
  })
```

and in  the client side we can use angular Interceptor to set the token in the header for all communication with the server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      HttpRequest,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpEvent,
      HttpInterceptor
    } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    @Injectable()
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor( {}
      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer localstorage.getItem(token)}`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
      }
    }
```

and the inject the Interceptor as a provider in the app.module

Comment: So, here's my doubt if client only needs to send the token then anyone can get the token and send it to the server at server side the token will be verified with the secret key, so where is the security ?

Comment: the client send to token encoded by the server it self  with a secret key that only the server know it so when ever he get an http call from any client he check the token first and decode it with the same secret key to see if the token is valid or not 
 the server doesn't  accept any token  this  kind of communication in theory it calls  asymmetric  cryptographie you can check this post to see where the security is https://medium.com/@vrypan/explaining-public-key-cryptography-to-non-geeks-f0994b3c2d5

Comment: Please pardon me but I am having difficulty in understanding this as I am new to it. Suppose the server sends you the token encoded by server itself with a secret key but ultimately it will be encoded string , Now I can hack that token and that string to server and server would send me the information , as the string will contain the secret key encoded by server.